# Django and ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Testing a basic ajax form and can't figure out why i'm getting the error 
**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cost'

I'm trying to follow this https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

It worked fine with one field, but getting the error when adding in more fields into the form, so i suspect it's a simple mistake

any thoughts?

The View

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_name = request.POST.get('the_name')
        post_cost = request.POST.get('the_cost')
        response_data = {}

        post = CostsForm(name=post_name, cost=post_cost)
        post.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
        response_data['postpk'] = post.pk
        response_data['name'] = post.name
        response_data['cost'] = post.cost
        response_data['created'] = post.created.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

Javascript

```
// AJAX for posting
function create_post() {
    console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url : "create_post/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : { the_name : $('#post-name').val(), the_cost : $('#post-cost').val()}, // data sent with the post request
        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            $('#post-name').val(''), $('#post-cost').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            $("#talk").prepend("<li id='post-"+json.postpk+"'><strong>"+json.name+"</strong> - <em> "+json.owner+"</em> - <span> "+json.created+
                "</span> - <a id='delete-post-"+json.postpk+"'>delete me</a></li>");
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },
        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

The form

```
class SundayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sunday
        fields = ['name','owner']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'id': 'post-name', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Sunday Name..'}
                ),
            'owner': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'id': 'post-owner','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Sunday Owner..'}
            )
        }


class CostsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Costs
        fields = ['name', 'cost']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.Select(
                attrs={'id': 'post-name', 'required': True}
                ),
            'cost': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'id': 'post-cost', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Sunday Cost'}
            )
        }
```

------------- EDIT ------------------
I think i've made some progress, i have the values coming in the the java script but `post.save()` isn't the right thing to use here, any thoughts

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_name = request.POST.get('the_name')
        post_cost = request.POST.get('the_cost')
        response_data = {}

        post = Costs(name_id=post_name, cost=post_cost)
        post.save()

        form = CostsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
            response_data['postpk'] = post.pk
            response_data['name'] = post.name_id
            response_data['cost'] = post.cost
            response_data['created'] = post.created.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p')

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you initialize forms at all. As the error says, the don't expect keyword arguments for the field values.

Also, you forgot to check whether the form was actually valid before saving; and, the pk is on the result of form.save, not on the form itself.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    post = CostsForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save()
        response_data[postpk] = post.pk
        ...
    else:
        # do something with form.errors; probably send them back in response_data
```

Comment: thanks @Daniel Roseman  I think i've made some progress and adding both in .. I get the values come through, but still a little stuck